# Kafka - Error in Instantiating Producer Class in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am using `Confluent.Kafka`

```
string kafkaEndpoint = "127.0.0.1:9092";

        string kafkaTopic = "testtopic";

        var producerConfig = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "bootstrap.servers", kafkaEndpoint } };

        using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(producerConfig, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
        {
            // Send 10 messages to the topic
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var message = $"Event {i}";
                var result = producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, null, message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine($"Event {i} sent on Partition: {result.Partition} with Offset: {result.Offset}");
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following compile time error:

> Producer.ProduceAsync(TopicPartition, Message)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Using `ProducerBuilder` like this:

```
var result = producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<Null, MyClass>{ Value = myObject}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

shows error:

```
Cannot convert from 'Confluent.Kafka.Message<Confluent.Kafka.Null, MyClass>' to 'Confluent.Kafka.Message<Confluent.Kafka.Null, string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Confluent.Kafka` nuget v1.0.1, `Producer` class is an internal class, that is it's not accessible. Looks like you need to use `ProducerBuilder` instead e.g. as:

```
var producerConfig = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "bootstrap.servers", kafkaEndpoint } };

using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(producerConfig)
    .SetKeySerializer(Serializers.Null)
    .SetValueSerializer(Serializers.Utf8)
    .Build())
{
    // Send 10 messages to the topic
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var message = $"Event {i}";
        var result = producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<Null, string>{ Value = message}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine($"Event {i} sent on Partition: {result.Partition} with Offset: {result.Offset}");
    }
}
```

Looks like an instance of arbitrary class could be sent as (substitute `MyClass` with target class):

```
        var result = producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<Null, MyClass>{ Value = myObject}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Yes. I have noticed that the class in internal. Do I need to use some other package to use it as in all the documentations i followed,they are using Producer class

Comment: Looks like no extra nugets required, just `Confluent.Kafka`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, ProducerBuilder requires `producerConfig` to be `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: Thanks @Renat. I tried to use `Producer` class as I want to send an instance of a class, not a message, How to pass an object using `ProducerBuilder`? I am trying Kafka for the first time, I don't have idea

Comment: @AdritaSharma , looks like changing message type from `string` to custom type would work: `producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<Null, MyClass>{ Value = myObject})...`

Comment: `producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<Null, MyClass>{ Value = myObject})` doesn't work. It shows error message `Cannot convert from 'Confluent.Kafka.Message<Confluent.Kafka.Null, MyClass>' to 'Confluent.Kafka.Message<Confluent.Kafka.Null, string>`